# CATIA V5 C# how to get AxisSystem from Active Document

Tags: c#, .net, catia

I'm trying to `update XAxis` on `Active CATIA` document using `C#`. Anyone knows how to do that? `somehowGetActiveAxisSysObject()` is `placeholder` in pseudo code:

```
                Array xMatrix = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), 3);
                xMatrix.SetValue(5.0, 0);
                xMatrix.SetValue(0.0, 1);
                xMatrix.SetValue(0.0, 2);
                MECMOD.AxisSystem targetAxisSys = **somehowGetActiveAxisSysObject();**
                targetAxisSys.PutXAxis(xMatrix);
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: Do you want to manipulate the "axis system" (Position/transformation matrix) of a Part in it's parent assembly? Or do you want to create/manipulate an axis system feature in a part which is marked "Current", meaning it will be used for the next point object created. A part is not required to have any Axis System features at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with Catia in C# so the code below may not run properly.

First, I will assume you are working in a part document and that you have created an axis system from the menu: `Insert->AxisSystems->AxisSystem` (or named something similar). Next, I will also assume that you went into this items properties and renamed it to "Larry".

```
MECMOD.AxisSystems thisPartsAxisSysCollection = (MECMOD.AxisSystems)Part.AxisSystems;
MECMOD.AxisSystem oneAxisSys = thisPartsAxisSysCollection(1); //Index is name unknown
//or
MECMOD.AxisSystem oneAxisSys = thisPartsAxisSysCollection("Larry");
oneAxisSys.PutXAxis("your data");
```

If this is not what you are trying to do, but instead are trying to move the part's origin then you will need to access `Part.OriginElements` instead and use that object's `PlaneXY, PlaneYZ, and PlaneZX`. Unfortunately those are read only if I remember correctly.